# why am I getting result=0.00000

Tags: c, variables

I'm trying to calculate sin and cos without using math library with taylor series witch is
**sinx =∑n=0 to n=∞ (-1)^n *  x^(2n+1) / (2n+1)!**
 and this code produces whatever the input is 0,00000 for sin 1,00000 for cos where is the problem in this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double fakt(int);
double power(int,int);
int negative_positive(int);
double calculate_sin(int,int);
double calculate_cos(int,int);
double calculate_radyan(int);

int main() {
    int degree,number;
    char command;
    do{
        scanf("%c",&command);
        if(command=='d' || command=='D'){
            scanf("%d %d",&degree,&number);
            double radyan = calculate_radyan(degree);
            printf("%lf \n%lf ",calculate_sin(radyan,number),calculate_cos(radyan,number));
        }
    }while(command!='e' && command!='E');

    return 0;
}

double fakt(int n){
    int i;
    double result=1;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        result = result*i;

    return result;
}

double power(int base, int exponent){
    int i;
    double result=1;
    for(i=0;i<exponent;i++)
        result = result*base;

    return result;
}

int negative_positive(int number){
    if(number % 2 == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}

double calculate_sin(int degree , int n){
    int i;
    double result=0;
    double tmp=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        tmp=negative_positive(i)*power(degree,2*i+1)/fakt(2*i+1);
        result=tmp+result;}
    return result;
}

double calculate_cos(int degree , int n){
    int i;
    double result=0;
    double tmp=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        tmp=negative_positive(i)*power(degree,i*2)/fakt(2*i);
        result=tmp+result;
    }

    return result;
}

double calculate_radyan(int degree){
    double result,pi=3.14159;
    result =pi/180*degree;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: have you tried printing out your intermediate values? Do they make sense, say inside the for loops?

Comment: yes ı tried each of them methods are giving correct numbers

Comment: and it isnt actually looks like this when ı copy my code inside of the code block it automaticly makes that

Comment: what inputs did you run the code with? It can produce other numbers too: http://ideone.com/BHXhDy

Comment: @user220910 Then edit the code after pasting it in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ı will answer my own question but ı found the solution. when program trys to go to power method with double radyan variable it converts that variable to 0 cause that method just takes integer variables power(double base,int exponent) is solved my problem

Comment: Does the compiler silently truncate the value from double to int? That's odd, have you asked it to hide warnings?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: it's implicit conversion.

Comment: Implicit conversion from double to int, which compiler does this?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: all of them? "A prvalue of floating-point type can be converted to prvalue of any integer type. The fractional part is truncated, that is, the fractional part is discarded. If the value can not fit into the destination type, the behavior is undefined." http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast  I'm too lazy to check the C standard, but this is just an old rule coming from C.